# How to setup threshold for triggered sends using ampscript in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send, campaign

Is there a way to set certain threshold for triggered sends in ampscript for 24 hours and error out sends if it exceeds the threshold using ampscript, the Sendable DE values are not helpful since it contains previous day data as well and "created on" field column is not available.

I thought of inserting each record in new DE at the time of send and check if the row count exceeds threshold. This is not working for large volume due to the delay.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Your solution seems possible, in theory. Just keep in mind that using the RaiseError function to keep the message from going out will still count as a send. I'd also consider using a retention policy on your DE rather than a timestamp so that you're not having to evaluate the date as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does it need to be real time? There are quite a few options you can do via Automation Studio and a Code Resource endpoint that can get this done for you, but it would be up to a 30 minute delay in sends.  You could also potentially look at having your API call hit a code resource instead of direct SFMC Endpoint where you can then do a lookup or similar to validate the number of calls that have been entered so far and if under threshold, then use the TSD wsproxy or REST API call to send, otherwise ignore or store in a DE for later send.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be real time. We are looking for ways to do it using ampscript.any options there?